# Can I open the Encyclopedia in-game?

Tags: macos, rome-2-total-war

Is there a way to open the Encyclopedia inside of Rome 2 Total War, as opposed to opening it in a web browser? Are there any Mods that will do this?

I'm looking for similar to the way the encyclopedia worked in the original Rome Total War.

**Clarification:**

When I right click on a card, it automatically opens up the online encyclopedia as opposed to an in-game one. Does running it on a Mac have anything to do with it? Or is there some setting I need to turn on to enable the offline one?

Comment: Only a mod could provide this, but I don't know any which is capable of this. At first it's weird, when you are used to the old system, but after time you will see it's way more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Total War Support Forum Wiki you can achieve this by editing the preferences.script file

> **Q: The Encyclopaedia minimises the game and opens a web browser. How can I view the Encyclopaedia in-game?**
>   A: This feature can be modified through the preferences.script file found in:
>   ~/library/The Creative Assembly/Rome2/scripts (for the Steam download)
>   ~/library/Containers/com.sega.mac.rome2/Data/Library/The Creative Assembly/Rome2/scripts (for the App store download)
>   Open the file and search for the term external_browser true; then change this to external_browser false; and re-save the preferences.script file. The Encyclopaedia will now open in-game.

**Reference:** https://forums.totalwar.com/discussion/137170/rome-ii-mac-version-faq

**Caution:** As always when editing configuration files, take a backup before editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need mods for this.

Pretty much, right clicking on anything with a "Card" in the bottom of the screen will bring up the Encyclopaedia entry for that item. For example, when viewing your army, your can right click on one of the units to go to the relevant place. Or right click on a technology in the technology tree.

You can also press the `F1` key, or the icon in the top-left of your screen, which will take you to the page for whatever "mode" you are in (battle, campaign). Helpfully, if you open the encyclopaedia while in a battle, it will pause it.

[image: There are several options for openning up the encyclopaedia.]

Comment: How do you do that though? Whenever I right click a card it opens up the online encyclopedia.

Comment: What do you mean? How is that different from what you want?

Comment: I want the encyclopedia to open up inside of the game. As in, I right click and the entry opens inside of the game. Right now, I right lick and it takes me out of the game to my web browser and displays an encyclopedia page there.

Comment: Hmm... must be a Mac thing, I guess. I'll try and install it on my Mac and see if I can find anything. :/

Comment: @TZHX you are exactly referring to online encyclopedia. In older titles like Empire, Medieval2 or Rome they had an offline encyclopedia integrated into a dialog window ingame. Since Shogun 2 they switched to an online encyclopedia, which opens in a browser like window.

Comment: I think you can enable this on mac by changing the preferences.script, see my answer on this question for details